# Whatsapp api cloud message type list not working with php

Tags: php, cpanel, whatsapi

I'm working with whatsapp api using php. Almost everything works fine but the list type messages.
When i select an item from the list and the message sent, it should trigger another event. In this case i created a list to select locations.
After selecting one location nothing happens but if the same location is written it works.

I can not find my error yet. Can anyone guide me please?
Like i said, if i select the location from the list nothing happens but if i write it it works.
This project is running on a shared cpanel.

I'm stuck where the location message should appear. The list type message works and sends the user selected option but the location does not appear. Sorry if i could not explain it better

Thanks a lot!

I'v tried to build it again lots of time using similar structure

This is the list type options and the location type messages i have so far

```
    $entry = $req["entry"][0];
    $changes = $entry["changes"][0];
    $value = $changes["value"];
    $objMessage = $value["messages"];
    $message = $objMessage[0];
    $text = $message["text"]["body"];
    $number = $text["from"];


  }else if (strpos($text, "list") !== false) {
    $data = json_encode([
      "messaging_product" => "whatsapp",
      "recipient_type" => "individual",
      "to" => $number,
      "type" => "interactive",
      "interactive" => [
        "type" => "list",
        "body" => [
          "text" => "BODY TEXT"
        ],
        "action" => [
          "button" => "BUTTON TEXT",
          "sections" => [
            [
              "title" => " LIST SECTION 1 TITLE",
              "rows" => [
                [
                  "id" => "LIST SECTION 1 ROW 1 ID",
                  "title" => "location1",
                  "description" => "SECTION 1 ROW 1 DESC"
                ],
                [
                  "id" => "LIST SECTION 1 ROW 2 ID",
                  "title" => "location2",
                  "description" => "SECTION 1 ROW 2 DESC"
                ]
              ]
            ],
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]);
  }else if (strpos($text, "location1") !== false) {
    $data = json_encode([
      "messaging_product" => "whatsapp",
      "recipient_type" => "individual",
      "to" => $number,
      "type"=> "location",
      "location"=> [
          "latitude"=> "41.89808194473385",
          "longitude"=> "12.49813575202307",
          "name"=> "Location1 Name",
          "address"=> "Location description"
      ]
    ]);
  }else if (strpos($comentario, "location2") !== false) {
    $data = json_encode([
      "messaging_product" => "whatsapp",
      "recipient_type" => "individual",
      "to" => $number,
      "type"=> "location",
      "location"=> [
          "latitude"=> "17.96589758757642",
          "longitude"=> "-76.79451717970731",
          "name"=> "Location2 name",
          "address"=> "Location description"
      ]
    ]);
  }
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? How is this problem related to cPanel?

Comment: I post these project using cpanel. What i've tried is to change the way for values storage, also tried to use nodejs but php is a must right now.

Comment: I'm stuck where the location message should appear. The list type message works and sends the user selected option but the location does not appear. Sorry if i could not explain it better.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. This should also include your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Just want to post the solution i found for this project.
I made some changes and it's working now.

First i want to clarify that the original problem was that the list type messages didn't triger the associated events like showing a location type message or something.

So i created a condition to declare the type of the message for every situation (One for text, one for interactive, one for location, and so)

With that everything works great now.

Here is the code i use to solve it.

```
$entry = $req["entry"][0];
$changes = $entry["changes"][0];
$value = $changes["value"];
$objectMessage = $value["messages"];
$message = $objectMessage[0];
$comment = $message["text"]["body"];
$number = $message["from"];
$type= $message["type"];

if ($type=== "text") {  // <-- This conditions solve my problem
  $comment = $message["text"]["body"];
} else if ($type=== "interactive") {
  $comment = $message["interactive"]["list_reply"]["title"];
} else if ($type=== "location") {
  $comment = $message["text"]["body"];
} else {
  ...
}
```